# Calculating exact volume of an irregular object

Tags: math, numerical-integration, maple

For an assignment I have to use numerical integration technique to calculate volume with cylindrical surface

> Ω={(x,y,z) in R³ with (x−0.5)² +(y−0.5)² ≤ 0.5²
>   and 0 ≤ z ≤ |ln(x+y)|}.

I have used Monte Carlo technique to calculate the volume. But to be sure the answer is correct I want to check the exact volume using Maple. I have been searching online on how to do it but couldn't find it.

So the question is, is there a way to calculate exact volume using Maple for that object or integral like
this:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question rather than a programming question.

Comment: Is this question asking for a "numerical integration technique" or for "exact volume"? Those two are different. Also, should there be an absolute value around the natural logarithm? It is in the graphic of the integral but not in your highlighted text.

Comment: In Mathematica, I'd integrate x from 0 to 1 and inside integrate y from 0 to sqrt(1-x^2) (I might have this slightly wrong, but that would be the general idea).

Comment: @RoryDaulton the absolute value has to be there. As I have described, I have used numerical Integration technique to calculate the volume and now to check if my result is right, I want to use Maple to calculate the exact volume. The another reason to calculate the exact value is to know how many random points are required to get close to the exact result.

JohnColeman Maple is used for programming, or I'm wrong?

Comment: @user3466563 Of course Maple is used for programming. But simply invoking its integration function isn't programming Maple. The Stack Overflow `maple` tag is concerned with Maple *programming* (using its built-in programming language). I suspect that you are not trying to write an actual program in Maple. If you are familiar with Excel, it is sort of the difference between simply using a built-in spreadsheet function and using VBA to write your own functions.

Comment: @user3466563 The site [mathematics.se] also has a `maple` tag -- one which is actually more active than the corresponding tag on Stack Overflow. I am not trying to be difficult. You really are more likely to get a good answer there, probably in just a few minutes. I recommend deleting the question here (so as to not cross-post) and posting it there instead.

Comment: Since you can't get an exact answer, you should use plain numerical integration over two variables to get a good, approximate answer. That would also check your Monte Carlo answer and would probably be more accurate.

Comment: It is possible to get exact solution by using Maple according to my teacher. I got 0.255305 by using Monte Carlos technique. To check the accuracy I'd like to calculate the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

The volume is the integral of

```
V = int_0^1 
        int_{0.5-sqrt(0.5^2-(x-0.5)^2)}^{0.5+sqrt(0.5^2-(x-0.5)^2)} 
            int_0^{abs(log(x+y))} 
                1 dz dy dx
```

or, after a change of variables,

```
V = int_-1^1
        int_{-sqrt(1-x^2)}^{+sqrt(1-x^2)}
            0.25 * abs(log(x/2+y/2+1)) dy dx
```

Computer algebra systems can compute the value to

```
V = 0.25502
```

(e.g., https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_-1%5E1+int_%7B-sqrt(1-x%5E2)%7D%5E%7B%2Bsqrt(1-x%5E2)%7D+1%2F4+*+abs(log(x%2F2%2By%2F2%2B1))+dy+dx).